# React Native Firebase build error

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native

I've been struggling with getting my react native instance to run and i keep hitting this:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/alexvallejo/Sites/myProj/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFirebase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/BannerComponent.o /Users/alexvallejo/Sites/myProj/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/admob/BannerComponent.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/alexvallejo/Sites/myProj/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFirebase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NativeExpressComponent.o /Users/alexvallejo/Sites/myProj/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/admob/NativeExpressComponent.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)


Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myProj.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain, code=4):
Failed to chmod /Users/alexvallejo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/31C5C7FC-9DE4-4F95-A7F5-50296C8CC6CB/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.containermanagerd/Bundle/Application/0170A665-460A-4CDF-92B4-0FAC8FBE2224/myProj.app/myProj : No such file or directory
Launching org.reactjs.native.example.myProj
```

Any ideas on what's going on here? I dont have `pod 'Firebase/AdMob'` in my Podfile so i don't know why BannerComponent is trying to load.

Comment: What happens if you run `pod install`? Maybe that `Firebase/AdMob` is a dependency of another module.

Comment: did you solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem just now.

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra I believe I ended up installing the AdMob pod. But I know i've had to go through a few iterations on setting up the project. Pods can be tricky with a RN project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're building with the latest Xcode version. Had the same issue with outdated Xcode.